# Is there a LAPACK function for zeroing out the upper / lower corner of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, lapack, blas, scientific-computing

Some LAPACK functions (like `dgqrf`) return a function where the answer is upper triangular but then there's some auxilary information stored below the diagonal. I'm wondering if there's a function that will zero out the below the diagonal entries.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General Problem**

No, there is no such function in standard BLAS/LAPACK.

If you are willing to move from using BLAS/LAPACK functions directly (with all potential issues and side effects), you may find linear algebra packages that would make such operations easier. Say, [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) would provide [TriangularViews](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1TriangularView.html), while other packages would have their way of doing that.

If you have to use BLAS/LAPACK directly, you would have to zero out it yourself.

**QR-decomposition**

I assume that you don't need the Q from the QR decomposition and only care about the R. With that, you want to store it in place and clean and avoid doing a copy into another allocated storage.

Technically, you can do it using [dormqr](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/dormqr.f.html) and setting matrix C to be a zero-matrix. However, it is not efficient, as you are actually performing not needed linear algebra operations and storing another dense matrix. You are certainly better off doing a manual loop to clean up if that is actually required or copy R into another place ([similar to how it's done here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29408035/2452869)).