# LAPACKE_dgeqrf/LAPACKE_dorgqr: How to generate matrix Q of the QR factorization of an orthogonal matrix that has more rows than columns

Tags: linear-algebra, lapack, intel-mkl, lapacke, qr-decomposition

**Introduction**:

I'm using the [Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onemkl.html#gs.3y36b4) functions [`LAPACKE_dgeqrf`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-c/2023-1/geqrf.html) and [`LAPACKE_dorgqr`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-c/2023-1/ormqr.html#GUID-58268D68-68D4-4F4D-A91D-EB0B380CCF3D) for generating the [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) of a general input matrix *A* of size *(m x n)* stored in *row-major* order, (where *m* is the number of *A*'s rows and *n* is the number of *A*'s columns).

Below is the code I use:

***C++ Code*:**

```
void qr (double *Q, double *R, double *A, const size_t m, const size_t n) {
    std::size_t k = std::max(std::size_t(1), std::min(m, n)); // The number of elementary reflectors

    std::unique_ptr<double[]> tau(new double[k]); // Scalars that define elementary reflectors

    LAPACKE_dgeqrf(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, m, n, A, n, tau.get());

    // Generate R matrix
    for (std::size_t i(0); i < n; ++i) {
        std::memset(R + i * n    , 0            , i       * sizeof(double));
        std::memcpy(R + i * n + i, A + i * n + i, (n - i) * sizeof(double));
    }

    // Generate Q matrix
    LAPACKE_dorgqr(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, m, k, k, A, n, tau.get());

    if(m == n) {
        std::memcpy(Q, A, sizeof(double) * (m * m));
    } else {
        for(std::size_t i(0); i < m; ++i) {
            std::memcpy(Q + i * k, A + i * n, sizeof(double) * (k));
        }
    }
}
```

**Related Info**:

The code above is a slightly refactored version of the code I found in another related answer to a similar question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29408035/2352671

**Description**:

- [`LAPACKE_dgeqrf`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-c/2023-1/geqrf.html) overwrites on the upper triangular part of input matrix *A*, the upper triangular part of *(mxn)* upper triangular matrix *R*. So matrix *R* can be easily extracted as shown in the code.
- The lower triangular part of the overwritten matrix, *A*, holds information about the Householder transformations.
- In array *tau* the scalar factors of the elementary reflectors used in the Householder transformations are stored.
- In order to extract matrix *Q* from the above given information, we use [`LAPACKE_dorgqr`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-c/2023-1/ormqr.html#GUID-58268D68-68D4-4F4D-A91D-EB0B380CCF3D).
- [`LAPACKE_dorgqr`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-c/2023-1/ormqr.html#GUID-58268D68-68D4-4F4D-A91D-EB0B380CCF3D) seems to work well for input matrices where *(m ≤ n)* (i.e., the number of rows of input matrix *A* is less than or equal to the number of its columns). That is, when *(m == n)*, [`LAPACKE_dorgqr`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-c/2023-1/ormqr.html#GUID-58268D68-68D4-4F4D-A91D-EB0B380CCF3D) overwrites on input matrix *A*, which as shown is the result of [`LAPACKE_dgeqrf`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-c/2023-1/geqrf.html), *(mxm)* matrix *Q*. When *(m < n)* first m columns of overwritten matrix A represent *(mxm)* matrix *Q*. So in these cases as illustrated in the code, *Q* can be easily extracted.
- However, **in the case where *(m > n)*** (i.e., the number of rows of input matrix *A* is greater than the number of its columns), [`LAPACKE_dorgqr`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-c/2023-1/ormqr.html#GUID-58268D68-68D4-4F4D-A91D-EB0B380CCF3D) **outputs only the first *n* columns of matrix *Q***.

**Questions**:

- How to generate the rest of the missing columns of *Q* in the case where the input matrix's rows are greater than the number of its columns?
- Am I missing something? That is, am I misusing the API?
- Is this API's normal behavior, and I've to generate the rest of the column orthogonal vectors of matrix *Q* using some generation process like Gram–Schmidt from the existing orthogonal column vectors?
- Do I have to solve a system for obtaining the full matrix Q, since I have matrix R?

Comment: As mentioned, You can generate the missing columns of Q using the Gram-Schmidt process on the remaining columns of A.

You are not misusing the API as the LAPACKE_dorgqr behaves as intended in generating the orthogonal matrix Q based on the number of columns of the input matrix A.

Yes, you can use the Gram-Schmidt process to generate the missing columns of Q.

Comment: @Shanmukh-Intel I solved the problem via padding zero filled columns, so that input matrix A becomes a square matrix. Is this correct?