# Full orthogonal-triangular (QR) decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, lapack, matrix-decomposition

I want to calculate a full orthogonal-triangular (QR) decomposition using LAPack. The post [How to get the Q from the QR factorization output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395461/how-to-get-the-q-from-the-qr-factorization-output) proposes to use ?GEQRF first and the get "Q" by using DORGQR/ZUNGQR. Unfortunately, this gives only the first N columns and not a orthogonal matrix Q in the case of M>N (more rows than columns). How do calculate "the rest" of Q to get a fully orthogonal square matrix Q?

I was using LAPAck ?GEQRF and DORGQR/ZUNGQR as stated in [How to get the Q from the QR factorization output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395461/how-to-get-the-q-from-the-qr-factorization-output).